# How to format only certain cells using vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to change the background color for columns A and B starting from Row 4 and upto the row that contains data. The following code doesn't seem to work. Please review.

```
Sub GeneralColorForAllPopulatedCells()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim g As Long, h As Long
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim rng As Range

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")

g = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
h = ws.Range("B" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

If g > h Then
    lastRow = g
Else
    lastRow = h
End If

Set rng = ws.Range("A4:B" & lastRow)
rng.Interior.Color = RGB(204, 229, 255)


End Sub
```

Thanks,
Hema

Comment: How isn't it working for you? (Meaning what is it doing wrong, or isn't it doing?)  It seems to work for me. I have data in `A1:B16`, and it highlighted `A4:B16` blue-ish.

Comment: Yes...it does seem to work now. I had misplaced it in the code. Thanks for the review. Your comment did make me understand that my code is indeed working. I'm new to VBA and learning! Thanks!

Comment: No worries! FYI, you can replace your code from `g = ...` to `End If` with a single line, `lastRow = WorksheetFunction.Max(ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row, ws.Range("B" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)`.  That uses the `MAX()` function to just choose the larger row. No need for `g`, `h`, or the `If` statement :D